# Asignar ID a una palabra que coincida en una

Tags: r, regex, string

Se tiene

```
palabras<- c("coche", "casa", "casona", "cielo", "ciclo")
```

Lista:
ID  Palabra a coincidir

```
1.1 coche
2.2 casa
3.3 cielo
```

Resultado:

```
palabras <- "1.1 coche" "2.2 casa" "casona" "3.3 cielo" "ciclo"
```

Comment: ¿Qué estás preguntando? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Lenguaje?

Comment: Bienvenido @Jrmz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien la pregunta las variables de entrada son sólo dos vectores:

```
palabras <- c("coche", "casa", "casona", "cielo", "ciclo")
reEnPalabras <- c("1.1 coche", "2.2 casa", "3.3 cielo")
```

En este caso en el vector `reEnPalabras` habría que removerle los números, el punto y los espacios porque es de la forma:

```
 `n.n_`
```

Donde `_` underline es espacio (para que se aprecie) y `n` un número de un dígito del `0` al `9` puede emplearse el patrón `"\\d\\.\\d\\s"` pero... si se tuviera `1.13` ya no funcionaría.

En su lugar se emplea el operador or: `|` con la siguiente expresión `"[0-9]|[.]|[ ]"` a fin de evitar lo anterior y se colapsa con `""` dentro la función `gsub`

```
coincidir <- gsub("[0-9]|[.]|[ ]", "", reEnPalabras)
coincidir
# "coche" "casa"  "cielo"
```

Luego con `which` se puede verificar que indices del vector `palabras` contienen los valores del vector `coincidir`:

```
which(palabras %in% coincidir)
# 1 2 4
```

> Por tanto resumiendo quedaría así:

```
palabras <- c("coche", "casa", "casona", "cielo", "ciclo")
reEnPalabras <- c("1.1 coche", "2.2 casa", "3.3 cielo")

coincidir <- gsub("[0-9]|[.]|[ ]", "", reEnPalabras)
palabras[which(palabras %in% coincidir)] <- reEnPalabras
palabras

# "13.13 coche" "2.2 casa"    "casona"      "3.3 cielo"   "ciclo"
```

Adicionalmente el vector `reEnPalabras` podría provenir de un `data.frame` también:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1.1,2.2,3.3), p=c("coche", "casa",  "cielo"))
df

#    ID     p
# 1 1.1 coche
# 2 2.2  casa
# 3 3.3 cielo

reEnPalabras <- do.call(paste, c(df)) # o si hay más columnas:
                                      # do.call(paste, c(df[,c("ID","p")]))
reEnPalabras

# "1.1 coche" "2.2 casa"  "3.3 cielo"
```

Y se siguen los pasos anteriores

Comment: Es parecido, no supe como explicarlo.Tengo una lista de palabras "X",. de esa lista se debe buscar la cadena en otro archivo donde tiene asignado un ID.
Como ejemplo tengo mi lista de palabras:
palabra<-  `c("ABARROTES","CASA", "AGRICULTOR")`

y tengo un archivo xlsx, donde se debe buscar la palabra  registro a registro, y en caso de que coincida en palabra asignar el ID que le corresponda.

Tengo este códigom donde busca  el patrón y lo reemplaza por el ID solamente. Como referencia:

ID Palabra a coindicir
11 CAMPO
33 VENDEDOR
22 AGRICULTOR
55 CASA
44 AGRICOLAS
77 ABARROTES

Comment: `L1<- read_excel("sd.xlsx")` (palabras que pueden coincidir)
`x<- c(palabra)# string

words.corpus <-  c(L1$`sd`) #  patrón
idwords.corpus <- c(L1$`ID`) # reemplazo

words.corpus <- paste0("\\b",idwords.corpus,"\\b|\\b",words.corpus,"\\b")

vect.corpus <- goodwords.corpus
names(vect.corpus) <- badwords.corpus`

Comment: Y el resultado que me da es este:


el resultado que me da es este:

V1
ABARROTES                             \b11\b|\b             CAMPO\b
CASA                                           \b33\b|\b             VENDEDOR\b
AGRICULTOR                            \b22\b|\b             AGRICULTOR\b
ALBAÑIL AYUDANTE                  \b55\b|\b          CASA\b
AYUDAR                                       \b44\b|\b         AGRICOLAS\b
ABARROTES                                 \b77\b|\           bABARROTES\b

Comment: Te sugiero @Jrmz entonces que edites la pregunta siguiendo los pasos contenidos en [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Voy a mejorar la redacción y ser más especifica, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo a lo mejor estas buscando:

```
palabras[palabras == 'coche'] <- '1.1 coche'
palabras[palabras == 'casa'] <- '2.2 casa'
palabras[palabras == 'cielo'] <- '3.3 cielo'
```

Te recomiendo ser más explicito en futuras preguntas para que se entienda mejor lo que estas buscando.